# Can two processes running simultaneously share a variable?

Tags: python, linux, process, cuda

Newbie here, I recon this may be a very foolish question. I am simultaneously running on cuda, in two distinct processes, a simple 3-layer MLP neural network over two different datasets.
Since these two processes are practically using the same script, they are both creating variables with the same names, so my question is: is each process completely isolated from the other, or is there any way that by running one process after the other I will be overwriting my variables, e.g. my variable x, pertaining to the dataset #1's feature vector I'm giving the model in the first process will be overwritten with the dataset #2's feature vector once I start process 2, therefore influencing my first process's model's predictions?

Comment: The processes have their own memory which means the variables are separate... unless the script does something to make that not so. For instance, if using shared memory or writing to like named files. So, generally, no they don't interfere.

Comment: @tdelaney "shared memory" in the context of CUDA could lead to confusion. You mean shred memory on the CPU.

Comment: Normally not, but the available GPU memory per process is of course less, if both models run at the same time. And it could be that certain algorithmic steps/kernels run one after the other instead of at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

> is each process completely isolated from the other, or is there any way that by running one process after the other I will be overwriting my variables, e.g. my variable x, pertaining to the dataset #1's feature vector I'm giving the model in the first process will be overwritten with the dataset #2's feature vector once I start process 2, therefore influencing my first process's model's predictions?

The processes are isolated from each other. One process will not overwrite variables in another process that happen to have the same "name".